# How to find lines containing any string from another file?

Tags: shell, grep, intersect

I have 2 csv files. File A, with multiple columns. File B, with one column.
eg.:

File A:

```
chr1 100000 100022 A C GeneX
chr2 200000 200033 X GeneY
chr3 300000 300055 G A GeneZ
```

File B:

```
GeneY
GeneZ
```

I would want my output to be:

```
chr2 200000 200033 X GeneY
chr3 300000 300055 G A GeneZ
```

I have tried using `grep` (which crashes) and others.
I am certain there must be a very simple answer to this that I just can't see!

Comment: Which platform are you on if `grep` crashes?  How big are the files that you're working with?  You said that you got an 'out of memory' error when you tried `grep -f FileB FileA`.  Your best bet in that case is probably to split `FileB` into sections small enough to be processed without `grep` crashing.  The obvious disadvantage of this is that you will end up with rows in the result set that are out of order compared with the original `FileA`.  If two words from `FileB` can appear in a single line, then you could also end up with repeats.

Comment: Does `sed` work any better?  What about Perl? If neither `sed` nor `grep` nor Perl works, then you may be able to find a better way to encode the information and write your own processing.  But that's something of a last resort, depending on a lot of factors not yet described in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't been able to get sed to work.

Comment: Bad luck.  Please identify the platform you're working on, and the sizes of the two files (line count and size in bytes for both files would be useful).

Comment: I've been trying to use unix in a bash terminal. File A is just 1 column of 1500 lines. File B is 1.2M, with 5800.

Comment: Which version of Unix? Those are tiny files! I was assuming you meant millions of records in the list of names, and gigabytes of in the main file. OK; so maybe they aren't tiny, but they are not, by any stretch of the imagination, big.  Maybe you need to get GNU `grep` installed? It will be quicker and simpler than most of the alternatives.  (I just tried doing `grep -f FileA` with a file containing 1500 generated lines such as `GZX6274256PQA` (a seven digit random number sandwiched between two constant strings) and it started up without a problem on my Mac, using BSD `grep`, rather than GNU.

Comment: Yes, they are not that big, which is why I am struggling. I'm on Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0.

Comment: So that's Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.5, I guess.  I was able to run `grep -f FileA` with a similar file (new set of random numbers, different sandwiching letters) without problems.  That's got 16 GiB main memory; I don't know if you're memory constrained -- the memory pressure on my machine is non-existent (11 GiB used, so 5 GiB available) -- see Activity Monitor / Memory tab.  Have you rebooted since you ran into trouble?  (I hate suggesting that, but it can help surprisingly/depressingly often.)

Comment: See this post: [Fastest way to find lines of a file from another larger file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-file-from-another-larger-file-in-bash)

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep -f`

```
grep -f FileB FileA
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. Unfortunately I get an out of memory error message with grep when I try to run this on large datasets.

Comment: @ChrisDias - You can try after setting locale with `export LC_ALL=C`. Source - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11777835

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} {for (i in a) if (i~$1) print i}' FileA FileB
chr2 200000 200033 X GeneY
chr3 300000 300055 G A GeneZ
```

Or like this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} ($NF in a)' FileB FileA
chr2 200000 200033 X GeneY
chr3 300000 300055 G A GeneZ
```

Comment: Thanks Jotne. I tried this, but got an empty output. I have the files as both .csv and tab delimited .txt; neither worked.

Comment: @ChrisDias It does works fine with your data above.  Then your data differs in format.