# How to quickly search for a substring and surrounding characters in a large string?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, substring

I have a file from which I need to find 10 characters before and after every substring instance.

For example, from:

```sh
(1M characters)...ldkS9jfasdfalkasjFalskdfjsDljBASHcslakfjsalZkf4djfsa3Jkjl...(1M characters)
```

I would like the output:

```sh
lskdfjsDljBASHcslakfjsal
```

Of course, in the file there are many instances of the string, and I would like to return all of them in the same manner of having the previous and subsequent 10 characters.

Right now I am using `grep` as follows:

```sh
grep -o -P '.{0,10}BASH.{0,10}' input.txt > output.txt
```

While this works, it seems to be very slow.  Is there any way to speed up the process?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're searching for 0 to 10 characters before and after the string, rather than just exactly 10? From how you described your issue, it seems like there will always be at least 10 on either side (and if there's an instance of the string near the very beginning or end of the input, that can be caught with an additional, trivially quick step). `.{10}BASH.{10}` should be much, much faster.

Comment: Thank you CAustin, I will try this.  To be honest I thought {0,10} meant every character from position 0 to 10.  I only want specifically 10 characters on either side.

Comment: @FightingTime nope, it means BASH preceded with atleast 0 char and atmost 10 char. So for this `BASHsad` string where BASH exists at the start , your regex should find a match where Austin's won't because `BASH` preceded by 0 char

Comment: Also see questions like [Fastest possible grep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9066609/608639), [Fastest way to find lines of a file from another larger file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42239179/608639) and [Fast string search in a very large file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37693682/608639).

Comment: try `awk -v RS='.{10}BASH.{10}' '{print RT}'`... also, if input is all ASCII, using `LC_ALL=C awk -v RS='.{10}BASH.{10}' '{print RT}'` will give better results... same with grep... `LC_ALL=C grep -oE '.{10}BASH.{10}'`

Comment: Thank you all for the very helpful answers.  I found them all very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you try the following:

```
grep -F 'BASH' input.txt | grep -o -E '.{10}BASH.{10}'
```

Cascading multiple `grep`s may in general look like an antipattern due to
poorly-designed search patterns.
In this case it works as follows: the 1st `grep` efficiently narrows down
the lines which contain the target word with the `-F` (fixed) option;
then the 2nd `grep` works to extract the substrings surrounding the word.

I have generated a text file with random characters of 100,000 columns
and 10,000 lines (1Gbytes). Here is the benchmark result with an
old Celeron CPU:

```
time grep -o -P '.{0,10}BASH.{0,10}' input.txt
=> 2m48s

time grep -F 'BASH' input.txt | grep -o -E '.{10}BASH.{10}'
=> 0m20s
```

BTW surprisingly I found nine `BASH` strings in the randomly generated
ascii file.

**[EDIT]**

If you need to keep overlapping matches, please try:

```
grep -F 'BASH' file | perl -ne 'while (/(?=(.{10}BASH.{10}))/g) {print $1, "\n"}'
```

It requires no additional execution time compared to the answer above.

Comment: Note that the -o option only reports non-overlapping matches, so occurrences of BASH that are too close together will not be reported separately using this technique.

Comment: @peak thanks for the comment. You're right, but the OP's code also specifies `-o` option and I don't think the result differs from the OP's one in this sense. If we need to separate overlapping substrings, it will be achieved with small amount of additional time. It depends on the OP's requirements anyway.

Comment: Understood, but the discrepancy between the main problem statement ("I need to find 10 characters before and after every substring instance") and the various proposed solutions so far might not be obvious to everyone.  Of course, it might not be important either :-)

Comment: @peak I see. Understood. I will study further in the background.:)

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  As peak mentioned, I need to keep overlapping matches, but at this point I prefer speed over the loss of some of those matches. 
 In the future, I may use this thread to address the issue. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276159/grep-that-works-with-overlapping-patterns

Comment: I've updated my answer with a version which keeps overlapping matches. I do appreciate the comment by @peak .

Comment: nice answer.. for time comparison, not sure why you are using `grep -o -P '.{0,10}BASH.{0,10}'` instead of `grep -oE '.{10}BASH.{10}'` ... also, if you have ripgrep, could you check how `rg -oP '.{10}BASH(?=(.{10}))' -r '$0$1'` performs?

Comment: I can safely say that whereas my previous code without splitting the file is still running since yesterday for a single operation, the above perl code took around 5 minutes to complete.  The key was to parse the lines into segments first (I did around 60 characters per line).  Thanks!

Comment: @Sundeep Thank you for the comment. As for the time comparison, I didn't put
a deep meaning by changing `{0,10}` to `{10}`. I should have changed
the conditions one by one. Indeed there is no difference in time between
`{0,10}` and `{10}`. It may be better to use `{0,10}` considering the
case the target word is located in the beginning or ending of the line.
I've installed `rg` and measured the performance with your suggested code.
It took 40sec in the same condition. Amazingly faster than the original
`grep` but my proposal seems to be still efficient. BR.

Comment: @FightingTime Thank you for the feedback. My pleasure to know it's working. BR.

Comment: @Sundeep I've also tested: `rg -F 'BASH' file | rg -oP '.{10}BASH(?=(.{10}))' -r '$0$1'
which turns out to take only 0.6 sec!

Answer (score 1):

> I have a file from which I need to find 10 characters before and after every substring instance.

Interpreted literally, this means that naive uses of `grep -o` cannot in general meet the requirements, because this option only reports non-overlapping sequences.

To illustrate, suppose for simplicity that the substring of interest is "X", and that the window on either side must have length 3.

Then given the string "aaaXaaXaaa" the output (according to the requirement statement) must be the two lines:

```
aaaXaaX
XaaXaaa
```

Here's a script that illustrates a solution using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq):

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in X aXa aaaXaaa aaaXaaXaaa aaaXXaaa
do
  echo $x ::
  jq -Rrs --arg ss X --argjson n 3 '
    . as $in
    | indices($ss)[] as $i
    | select($i-$n >=0 and $i+$n <= length)
    | $in[$i-$n:$i+$n+1]' <<< "$x"
  echo
done
```

Note that the -s option here in effect causes control characters, such as newline, to be regarded as single characters.

### Output

```
X ::

aXa ::

aaaXaaa ::
aaaXaaa

aaaXaaXaaa ::
aaaXaaX
XaaXaaa

aaaXXaaa ::
aaaXXaa
aaXXaaa
```