# Grepping a single regular expression for a very large file

Tags: regex, xml, bash, gnu-parallel

`file.xml` is a large 74G file, I have to grep a single regular expression against it as fast as possible. I'm trying to do this by using GNU `parallel`:

```
parallel --pipe --block 10M --ungroup LC_ALL=C grep -iF "test.*pattern" < file.xml
```

1. How can I implement this by using `--pipepart` since it's faster than `--pipe`?
2. Does it get faster by increasing or decreasing size of blocks (example 20M instead of 10M, or 10M instead of 20M)?

Comment: You'll have to test to be sure, but my expectation is that trying to parallelize it like this will *not* work -- I expect the overhead from having `parallel` read, split, and pipe the file's contents to `grep` will make it slower than having a single `grep` process read the file directly.

Comment: @GordonDavisson my command is a fork from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067042/13641553), it's not entirely my idea.

Comment: In that one, `parallel` isn't processing the bulk data, it's just handing out filenames to `grep` commands and having them read the files directly. In that situation, parallelizing it does make sense.

Comment: A 74Gigabytes XML file is a creepy combination. Opened tag at the beginning need reading the whole 74G to find its closing. By its nature XML is a serial data format and add a nested structure at that. I really wonder what kind of twist motivated choosing XML for such a large dataset to be searched at that.

Comment: In general the disk I/O will be the bottleneck which cannot be accelerated with `parallel`. Please consider to introduce `ripgrep` (`rg`) which has a much better performance than `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

1.) The largest xml file I have is 11G so YMMV but using `parallel --pipepart LC_ALL=C grep -H -n 'searchterm' {} :::: file.xml` was faster than `parallel --pipe --block 10M --ungroup LC_ALL=C grep -iF "test.*pattern" < file.xml` and significantly faster than `grep "searchterm" file.xml`.

2.) I didn't specify a block size for the `parallel --pipepart` command above, but you can with the `--block` option; you'll need to try different block sizes yourself to see whether they speed up / slow down the search. Using `--block -1` provided the fastest speed on my system for this approach.

As [@tshiono](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8572380/tshiono) mentioned in the comments, try [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) - this was fastest on my test xml file (quicker than grep/parallel grep/anything else) and may prove to be a better solution for you overall.

**EDIT**
I tested [@Ole Tange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363028/ole-tange)'s suggested 'parallel + ripgrep' approach (`parallel --pipepart --block -1 LC_ALL=C rg 'Glu299SerfsTer21' {} :::: ClinVarFullRelease_00-latest.xml`) and it was ~the same as `rg 'Glu299SerfsTer21' ClinVarFullRelease_00-latest.xml` on my system. The difference was negligible, so the 'parallel + rg' approach may be best for a very large XML file. There are a number of potential reasons I didn't see the expected speedup, eg [@Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) suggestions in his comment above, but you would need to conduct comprehensive benchmarking with your own system to figure out the best approach.

(Thanks [Ole Tange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363028/ole-tange) for the suggestion and for creating such kick ass software)

Comment: I think the fastest you can go is `--pipepart --block -1` combined with `ripgrep`. `--block -1` splits the file into roughly evenly sized blocks - one per CPU thread.